# Using python datetime.datetime.strptime on windows with BST timezone

Tags: python, windows, timezone, binary-search-tree, strptime

I need to parse many different dates in many different formats. I am having trouble with the following and wondered if anyopne could explain why;

The following works on a linux system:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('Tue 23 Aug 2011 09:00:07 PM BST','%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p %Z')
```

But running under windows it raises

ValueError: time data does not match format

However, if I try GMT not BST on windows, it works fine;

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('Tue 23 Aug 2011 09:00:07 PM GMT','%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p %Z')
```

Is there a reason python does not understand the BST timezone under windows, but it works fine under Linux?

thanks,

Matt.

Comment: could `strptime` be implementation specific and the question isn't really about python, but about the c runtimes used by the interpreter?

Comment: I would say on top of that that your month has not to be in capital letters, try: **Aug** instead of AUG

Do you really need the timezone %Z ? maybe you can do without it...

Comment: -daren something to look into.. thanks    -   -kingpin The capital AUG was an error, well spotted! I will edit the OP to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, parsing a three-letter time zone code like this is not a good practice (unless of course you have no choice).  For example, "EST" is commonly used in the USA for UTC-4/5 and is also commonly used in Australia.  So any support for "EST" must therefore be dependent on locale.  It would not surprise me if "BST" was similarly ambiguous.

I highly recommend using the [`pytz`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) module in which British civil time is given the string identifier `Europe/London` and UTC is called `Etc/UTC`.  The `pytz` API will give consistent results regardless of the locale of the user or system running the application.

If you are working on a UI that must be tied to locale, or parsing inputs with formats you cannot change, then consider using a dictionary of abbreviations to `pytz` timezone objects.  For example: `{'BST': 'Europe/London'}`.  Then your application can work with UTC dates and times uniformly, which will greatly reduce the possibility of errors.

Comment: I am parsing squillions of dates of many different formats and with various locales. pytz sounds interesting, I'll take a look.

Comment: and you are right; BST is ambiguous, it is also 'Bangladesh Summer Time' !!

Comment: Since you need to support multiple different locales, you may run into an "EST" situation, where two users expect the same exact input to have a different meaning.  Beware and good luck.